# there exists an orthogonal transformation such that

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices

*Prove or Disprove*: There exists an orthogonal transformation *T*: $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3 $ such that
$$
        T\left(\begin{bmatrix}
        2  \\
        3  \\
        0  \\
        \end{bmatrix}\right)= 
        \begin{bmatrix}
        3 \\
        0 \\
        2 \\
        \end{bmatrix} and
        T\left(\begin{bmatrix}
        -3  \\
        2  \\
        0  \\
        \end{bmatrix}\right)= 
        \begin{bmatrix}
        2 \\
        -3 \\
        0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

I am not quite sure how to begin this problem. All I know is that a transformation *T*: $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n $ is orthogonal if T preserves length. Not quite sure how to proceed from there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If only you knew something about the angle between the vectors $(2,3,0)$ and $(-3,2,0)$ and then also about the angle between their images...

Comment: So dot (2,3,0) and (-3,2,0), getting -6+6+0=0. Then dot (3,0,2) and (2,-3,0), getting 6-0+0=6.

Comment: @AlexD : $0$ and $6$ are not angles (here).